# Why does everyone turn against Mlle Michonneau in Balzac's Père Goriot?

Tags: french-language, honore-de-balzac, le-pere-goriot

Why does everyone turn against Mlle Michonneau very suddenly after the arrest of Vautrin? (Even Rastignac, who knows that Vautrin's pal murdered Victorine's brother.)

Answer (score 1):

Because she was secretly meeting with the police,  when she learned that the was a reward for the capture of Vautrin,  who was well liked by everyone in the house... she was looked upon as a common snitch.